# What is mean $_

Tags: shell

What is mean by `$_` , It may used like this

```
mkdir testdirectory;cd $_
```

It will redirect to the new directory

> testdirectory

if i use like this , echo `$_`

It shows

> testdirectory

Which means previously created directory.Actually what it means, I don't know really

Comment: The duplicate question is not really an answer to this one.  It can be derived from that, but IMO that's not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> what it means, I don't know really

`$_` means the **last argument** to the previous command.

Example:

```
echo "FOO" "BAR"
FOO BAR
echo $_
BAR
```

Read more **[here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-shell-special-parameters/)**.